# How to edit the value of a column in a dataset in visual studio using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dataset

I am trying to edit the "Sex" value based on whether "Masculin" or "Feminin" is checked.

[image: program after build]

I figured out I will need another column in the dataset that accepts string (called "Sex" in the photo), besides the two checkboxes above (which they both have a column in the dataset that are boolean).

[image: dataset columns]

I also figured out I should add the code that does what I'm trying (edit column with final result and add it) in `angajatiBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click` function, but I have no idea
how to change the column "Sex"'s value to either Female or Male.

```cs
bool masculin = false;
bool feminin = false;

private void angajatiBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (masculin)
  {
    //I guess I should edit it here, but I don't know how.    
  }
  this.Validate();
  this.angajatiBindingSource.EndEdit();
  this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.modelDataSet);
}

//here I set the global boolean "masculin" to true or false.
private void sexCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(sexCheckBox.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
  {
    masculin = true;
  }
  else
  {
    masculin = false;
  }
}

//same for "Feminin" checkbox.
private void sex_FemininCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (sex_FemininCheckBox.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
  {
    feminin = true;
  }
  else
  {
    feminin = false;
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing it properly either (with the 3 columns and everything).

Comment: You don't need two bit columns for the sex property. In the database one column of type char with size 1 is enough (You can put here F/M and use that for your coding logic)

Comment: And for the UI, using a checkbox is not correct. Two radiobuttons are the logical choice here because setting one should unset the other and this doesn't happen automatically with checkboxes.

Comment: Oh I understand. I think radiobuttons look nicer, but as a plan B what you said is very viable too. Do you know how can I edit the value from "Sex" column? Is there a function or any sort? I can't find it.

Comment: Hello, you can try to extract the data first, if the gender is male, set radiobutton1 to male, and then click radiobutton1 to insert male into the database